# Why are values undefined when submit form with javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, google-visualization

**javascript:**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
$(function() {
  //
  $('#button_submit').click(function() {
    var start_date = $('start_date').val();
    var end_date = $('end_date').val();
    var type = $('type').val();
    alert(start_date);
  });
});
// 
function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "visits/day.php?start_date=" + start_date + "&end_date=" + end_date,
    dataType: "json",
    async: false
  }).responseText;

  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);


  var options = {
    title: 'Number of visitors'
  };

  if (type === 'pie') {
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(
      document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
  }
  if (type === 'bar') {
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(
      document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
  }
}
```

**html:**

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date"><br />
    <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date"><br />
    <input type="text" name="type" id="type"><br />
    <input type="button" id="button_submit" value="go">
</form>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Variables obtained by the form seem empty, ive did that alert(start_date) and says: undifined and are not passing through url:visits/day.php?start_date...

I need that values to send out for my php page without refresh the page

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should specify what support library you are using... I am guessing jQuery from the $() stuff, but there is more than one library that uses $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the above... I don't see where you're passing `start_date` and `end_date` to your `drawChart()` function:

Edited to add the call to drawChart()

```
$(function() {
  //
  $('#button_submit').click(function() {
    var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
    var end_date = $('#end_date').val();
    var type = $('#type').val();
    drawChart(start_date, end_date)
    console.log(start_date, end_date, type);
  });
});
function drawChart(start_date, end_date) {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "visits/day.php?start_date=" + start_date + "&end_date=" + end_date,
    dataType: "json",
    async: false
  }).responseText;
```

Comment: Done, but still No Data :s I hit the button, and nothing is changed. Firebug doesnt report any error

Comment: Did you try adding a call to `drawChart(start_date, end_date)` at the end of `$('#button_submit').click()` ?

Comment: Cheers.  Edited my example above in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 2):

```
var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
var end_date = $('#end_date').val();
var type = $('#type').val();
```

This will find the HTML elements by `id` (`#` followed by `id` value).

```
$('start_date').val();
```

the above would find the element with tag name `<start_date>`

Next, your variables have function visibility scope. So they are only defined (and visible) only within anonymous function (that is a callback for `button_submit` click handler).

Comment: Yes, -.- i miss that. Btw, button doesnt do anything :s I dont see values being sent and results dont appear, anything wrong with code?

Comment: @skdnewbie: remove it and write once again, line by line, checking that the code behaves like it is expected. It's called debugging and each developer should know how to debug their code.